# How to make sidebar navbar open by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a website with a collapsible sidebar navigation. It works fine when it's closed upon loading, but what I want to do is have it open by default with the ability to close and reopen.

Below is the code being used. If you need any other clarification, please let me know.

Like I said, the menu opens and closes fine, but I want the roles to be reversed where it starts open and then closes on click. I feel like it's something small I'm overlooking, but I'm just not sure.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
    overlay = $('.overlay'),
    isClosed = false;

  trigger.click(function() {
    hamburger_cross();
  });

  function hamburger_cross() {

    if (isClosed == true) {
      //overlay.hide();
      trigger.removeClass('is-open');
      trigger.addClass('is-closed');
      isClosed = false;
    } else {
      //overlay.show();
      trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
      trigger.addClass('is-open');
      isClosed = true;
    }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*           Wrappers            */

/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 220px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 220px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -220px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 220px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -220px;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*     Sidebar nav styles        */

/*-------------------------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
  background-color: #ec1b5a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
  background-color: #79aefe;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
  background-color: #314190;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
  background-color: #279636;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before {
  background-color: #7d5d81;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
  background-color: #ead24c;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
  background-color: #2d2366;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
  background-color: #35acdf;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(10):before {
  background-color: #ec1b5a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*       Hamburger-Cross         */

/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
  outline: none;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top {
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle {
  display: none;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*            Overlay            */

/*-------------------------------*/

/*.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,.8);
    z-index: 1;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
                       Brand
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Participant</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Interaction</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Fulfillment</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">References</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Admin</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
      <span class="hamb-top"></span>
      <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <h1>Quit Smoking</h1>
          <p>Why I want to quit I would save money. I would not smell like a stale cigarette. I would not have to look for a place to smoke all the time. My health would be better. I don't like feeling addicted. My family would stop nagging me to quit. Food
            would taste better. I would fit in better socially. I would feel better about my future. I would set a good example for my family and friends.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `class="toggled"` in `<div id="wrapper"  >` and `isClosed = true;`

and also change class of  `<button type="button" class="hamburger is-open" data-toggle="offcanvas">` for `is-closed` to `is-open`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
    overlay = $('.overlay'),
    isClosed = true;

  trigger.click(function() {
    hamburger_cross();
  });

  function hamburger_cross() {

    if (isClosed == true) {
      //overlay.hide();
      trigger.removeClass('is-open');
      trigger.addClass('is-closed');
      isClosed = false;
    } else {
      //overlay.show();
      trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
      trigger.addClass('is-open');
      isClosed = true;
    }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*           Wrappers            */

/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 220px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 220px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -220px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 220px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -220px;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*     Sidebar nav styles        */

/*-------------------------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
  background-color: #ec1b5a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
  background-color: #79aefe;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
  background-color: #314190;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
  background-color: #279636;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before {
  background-color: #7d5d81;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
  background-color: #ead24c;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
  background-color: #2d2366;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
  background-color: #35acdf;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(10):before {
  background-color: #ec1b5a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*       Hamburger-Cross         */

/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
  outline: none;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top {
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle {
  display: none;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*            Overlay            */

/*-------------------------------*/

/*.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,.8);
    z-index: 1;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper"  class="toggled" >
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
                       Brand
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Participant</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Interaction</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Fulfillment</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">References</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Admin</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="hamburger is-open" data-toggle="offcanvas">
      <span class="hamb-top"></span>
      <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
    </button>
   
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <h1>Quit Smoking</h1>
          <p>Why I want to quit I would save money. I would not smell like a stale cigarette. I would not have to look for a place to smoke all the time. My health would be better. I don't like feeling addicted. My family would stop nagging me to quit. Food
           
            would taste better. I would fit in better socially. I would feel better about my future. I would set a good example for my family and friends.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Simple oversight on my part which is what I figured. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: I cant resist refactoring your hamburger_cross() function as follows -->
`function hamburger_cross() {
  //hide or show
  trigger.toggleClass('is-open').toggleClass('is-closed');
  isClosed = !isClosed;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just invert your toggle class, of course then you must change button class to start showing it as open instead of closed. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
    overlay = $('.overlay'),
    isClosed = true;

  trigger.click(function() {
    hamburger_cross();
  });

  function hamburger_cross() {

    if (isClosed == true) {
      //overlay.hide();
      trigger.removeClass('is-open');
      trigger.addClass('is-closed');
      isClosed = false;
    } else {
      //overlay.show();
      trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
      trigger.addClass('is-open');
      isClosed = true;
    }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*           Wrappers            */

/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 220px; //Instead of 0px
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 0px; //Instead of 220px
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 220px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -220px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 220px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -220px;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*     Sidebar nav styles        */

/*-------------------------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
  background-color: #ec1b5a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
  background-color: #79aefe;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
  background-color: #314190;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
  background-color: #279636;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before {
  background-color: #7d5d81;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
  background-color: #ead24c;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
  background-color: #2d2366;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
  background-color: #35acdf;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(10):before {
  background-color: #ec1b5a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*       Hamburger-Cross         */

/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
  outline: none;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top {
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle {
  display: none;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*            Overlay            */

/*-------------------------------*/

/*.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,.8);
    z-index: 1;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
                       Brand
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Participant</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Interaction</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Fulfillment</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">References</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Admin</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="hamburger is-open" data-toggle="offcanvas">
      <span class="hamb-top"></span>
      <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <h1>Quit Smoking</h1>
          <p>Why I want to quit I would save money. I would not smell like a stale cigarette. I would not have to look for a place to smoke all the time. My health would be better. I don't like feeling addicted. My family would stop nagging me to quit. Food
            would taste better. I would fit in better socially. I would feel better about my future. I would set a good example for my family and friends.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to add the following to the end of your `$(document).ready` function.

```
$('.hamburger').trigger('click');
```

It could be the desirable result if you want to show your visitor the animation on page load.

https://jsfiddle.net/tb65wrfa/

Answer (score 0):

just add 
`trigger.trigger('click');` 
at the end of your document ready function. (dont put it outside)

what essentially we are doing is simulating a click on that hamburger icon as soon as document ready fires. so you dont need to change any of the existing code

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

just add class `toggled` in `id="wrapper"`

and add change `class="hamburger is-closed"` to `class="hamburger is-open"`

[Edited code](https://jsfiddle.net/bego4tce/)